# Using Jmeter to load test a Citrix web platform

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, tools, test-strategy

We have `Citrix XenApp` and `NetScaler` and we want to load test this environment for capacity planning.

Normal use is that a user installs `Citrix Receiver`, which installs a plugin for his web browser (`IE` or `Firefox`), then types the server URL to login through a web login form and then he can launch the desired application.

If `Citrix Receiver` isn't installed, it cannot access the web login form which would indicate, that it is not a standard web login form.

Using Jmeter proxy, I captured all the requests being sent out while performing the login operation. I try to replay the scenario, but I get a `403 forbidden error`. I made sure to capture cookies generated for the session as well as sending exact similar headers and data, but it doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone managed to make this work `Jmeter vs Citrix` through web interface ?

**Note:** There is an `ICA plugin` for `Jmeter`, but it looks like it is made as to work with a desktop `Citrix client`, not web.

Answer (score 2):

Our old friend Citrix.  We’ve done quite a few Citrix performance tests over the years.  Always technically challenging to script.

Youssef if I understand you correctly, I think your problem is that Citrix Receiver doesn't work the way you seem to think it does. It isn't a Web App, in the sense that it is communicating mouse clicks and key strokes in a form that you can usefully capture via the Jmeter proxy and then replay. The comprehensible HTTP(S) traffic just serves to set up the connection, at the end of which a Citrix ICA file containing one time only passwords is downloaded. Thereafter, the Receiver behaves pretty much as if Citrix is on the Desktop, and your load testing tool needs to do likewise.

Do let me know if that is not the issue.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Citrix needs a desktop automation tool, not jMeter which is web-based. Voted up. For windows Apps i have good experience with Coded UI: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681%28v=vs.100%29.aspx The MS stack also load testing tools.

Comment: Nigel Hoath is currect, if you use HTML5, you will be able to test it that way:
https://www.carlstalhood.com/storefront-3-5-basic-configuration/#html5 To stest using the reciver, refrence:
https://sourceforge.net/p/icafun/home/ICA%20Plugin%20for%20JMeter/

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2020, you can use this [new JMeter plugin](https://github.com/blazemeter/CitrixPlugin)

It allows recording, replaying and performance testing Citrix exposed applications.

It can be installed using jmeter-plugins-manager:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=citrix

To see how to install it:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/easily-manage-jmeter-plugins/

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://github.com/blazemeter/CitrixPlugin) will help you.